# Filesystem doesn't want to write a specific file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```js
console.log(`./settings/${mob.serverName}/${mob.channelName}.json`); // ./settings/Mobbot Test Server/mobtimusprime.json
fsp.writeFile(`./settings/${mob.serverName}/newfile.json`, settings); // actually creates the right file, in the right path
console.log(fs.existsSync(`./settings/${mob.serverName}`)); // true
fsp.writeFile(`./settings/${mob.serverName}/${mob.channelName}.json`, settings); // does nothing, doesn't throw an error, just does absolutely nothing.
```

I have no idea what is going on, I have checked for spelling multiple times, but everything seems like it **should** work, but doesn't.

additional information:
node -v // v14.2.0
windows 10

btw:

```js
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
```

in case that wasn't obvious.

Edit:
This is more like the thing I am trying to make (of course, minimum needed code to show the issue).

```js
const myFunc = async (settings) => {
  try {
    return await fsp.writeFile(`./settings/${mob.serverName}/${mob.channelName}.json`, settings);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Edit 2:

More context:

```js
const settingsUpdater = async (settings) => {
  try {
    return await fsp.writeFile(`./settings/${mob.serverName}/${mob.channelName}.json`, settings);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

const callingFunction = async (...args) {
  try {
    await settingsUpdater(settings);
    const { pieceOfUpdatedSettings } = require(`../settings/${mob.serverName}/${mob.channelName}.json`);
    anotherFunction(pieceOfUpdatedSettings); 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more info? When you said filesystem doesn't want to write, what actually happnes? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am getting no error whatsoever, the code just continues on as if nothing happened, and the file doesn't get created or updated.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I can't imagine what would be causing that. Just FWIW (not related to the specific problem), there's no need for `return await`, the value you return from an `async` function is always effectively `await`ed (e.g., just `return` is sufficient). `return await` *used* to cause the settlement of the function to take one extra async tick, but ES2019 fixed that (for native promises). Also strongly recommend not converting rejection into resolution with `undefined`, which is what that `catch` block does. :-) Hope you find the issue!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so you're saying I shouldn't have a catch block then?

Comment: I don't recommend the use of catch blocks and async functions. If you wanted to read a file with promises, it would be: `const fs = require('fs')` and `fs.readFile(path).then(res => { processing response... }).catch(err => { processing error... });`. You can also use callbacks. Hope it was of help.

Comment: Just because you're not familiar with modern syntax doesn't make it worse. It also doesn't help the problem in any way. @AirOne.

For now I have just made a new version of the bot that doesn't use storage at all, as it's not essential to have storage, it's just a fallback in case the server crashes for whatever reason.

Comment: I edited my previous answer, check before answering.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = './path/to/file'
const data = 'yourdata'

fs.appendFile(path, data, (err) => {
    if err console.log(err);
});
```

`fs.appendFile()` will create a file if not existing, or rewrite an ewisting one.
I used callbacks here, but you can also use synchronous functions of `fs`, instead of async ones, like this:

```
try {
    fs.appendFileSync(path, data);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Fs doc: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: you can't overwrite files?

The existsSync is just there so I can show that the path actually exists, it's not part of the actual code I want to make.       
     
The only line I actually want is the last line, the others are just there for bugfixing.       
      

> Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists. data can be a string or a buffer. The Promise will be resolved with no arguments upon success.